# Have Jenkins Ping Nodes at Quicker Intervals

Tags: jenkins, vmware, snapshot

I have a jenkins instance with a windows node on it with VMWare-cmd installed. When the build completes, the node reverts to a snapshot.

After reverting, it reboots.

The problem is Jenkins doesn't seem to notice the node disconnecting after the snapshot reversion (at least not right away) which can cause issues if I have another job start building it.

Is there anyway for Jenkins to notice the node has been disconnected faster?

Answer (score 0):

Try to launch the Jenkins with `-D hudson.slaves.ChannelPinger.pingIntervalSeconds $replace_with_your_new_interval`, or, try this command in jenkins script console from web portal `hudson.slaves.ComputerListener.all().find { it instanceof hudson.slaves.ChannelPinger }.pingIntervalSeconds = $replace_with_your_new_interval`.